# Cannot enter text in text fields on facebook on safari

Tags: facebook, macos, text, safari, enter

I cannot enter text in neither of the edit fields on my facebook site using Safari on Mac. Earlier it has worked. How can I resolve this? Facebook doesn't offer any support for not working things.

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions, not general support. that being said, just buy a real computer and throw that expensive mac away :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a user problem with the FB platform, and not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this isn't the right place to ask.

Try Refreshing, if you have no luck with that, possibly try it in Other Browsers, it may just be an issue with Safari.